# Add GIF on tabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller, gif

I have a UITabBarController, in which one of the tabBarItem needs to display a GIF. I tried using [3rd party library](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) to display GIF. But, the GIF displayed is distorted. Because it only accepts the 1x size. Is there any way to add GIF on single tabBarController. I do not want to use a custom TabBarController.
Here is my code to set GIF on tabBarItem

```
   UITabBarItem *tabBarItemAtIndex2 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    [tabBarItemAtIndex2 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"InstantTabBar.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
//    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"IJPTabBar", nil)];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"instant" withExtension:@"gif"];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    [tabBarItem1 setImage:img];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add GIF to TabBarItem. I used a 2x GIF and managed the `edgeInsets` of TabBarItem. Now, GIF is not blurry .